# List to string (but without quotes)

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, what is the proper filter to *'unquote'* a list?
What I'm currently doing is applying the `join` filter.

Example:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    some_ip: "{{ some_ip | default([]) + ['10.0.0.1'] }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ some_ip | join(' ') }}"
```

This will result in the desired value. However, when there is only one value, a join is not needed. And the `join` filter kind of implies there are multiple values to be set

Comment: `join` does nothing in the case of a list containing a single element, e.g.: `[1,2,3] | join(',')` will give `1,2,3` and not `1,2,3,`. So, this is the safest if you don't want to go into ugly templating and usage of `{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}`

Comment: But that all depends on you context. If the default is there to cover for `undefined` and that case only, then you'd be better of with `"{{ some_ip | default('') ~ '10.0.0.1' }}"`. On the other hand, if `some_ip` might, in some cases contains a list, then, you probably have the cleanest solution already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a look at the [List of Builtin Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters), I'm not sure if there's a particular filter that does what you'd like.

I think it's accepted that `join(' ')` will handle cases where there's 0 or more elements in the list. In the case of a single element there's nothing to concatenate, sure, but since I find myself using this function often, it becomes easier to rely on it for readability's sake.

In this case if you needed to be more explicit I'd use some conditional logic such as:

```
{{ some_ip | first if some_ip | length == 1 else (some_ip | join(' ')) }}
```

Which, IMO, is explicit, but a lot harder to read and really doesn't look very good with filters.

Comment: _In this case if you needed to be more explicit I'd use some conditional logic such as_ > which still does not accounts for when `some_ip == undefined`, so definitely, having a `join`'ed list is more readable.

Comment: True. Luckily in this case we have `default([])`; otherwise yes, that's yet another thing to consider and add to the clunkiness!

Comment: note; when i use `| join` it does _not_ add the space between the items in the list.

Comment: Good to know, and thanks for checking. I no realize I was confusing `split()` with the `join()` method, which does separate on whitespace by default (whereas join will just concatenate the strings.) I'll update my answer accordingly!